# Should I communicate with my Windows Workflow Host throught ExternalDataExchange or rather using WCF?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I know I can communicate with my Windows Workflow host (FROM my workflow) using either the ExternalDataExchange on an interface. Or I can communicate with my host using WCF using the SendActivity provided with .NET 3.5.

I am not sure which method I should choose. Any suggestions on the pro's and con's of these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our application we use WF from within an IIS appl pool. As for communication, we use WCF (SendActivities or custom proxies based on the contract). As long as you can reference the assembly, it works like a charm.

If you want to communicate with the WF host, you will most likely need to code more.